# SQL query on button click with ID

Tags: php, html, mysql

So I am very new to php but I want to create a ticket system based on a mysql database.

So my problem right now is that I want to close a ticket when I press a butten. My Tickets are displayed in a table and I dont't know how I can specify the dataset in my update function once I press the button.

This is what i got so far:

```
$con = mysqli_connect($ip, $user, $pw, $db);
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}

if($show_updates == 'true') {
    echo file_get_contents('http://zombieland.eu/api/sht/update-1.2.php');    
}

$page_query = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM `SHT_Tickets` WHERE `status`='OPEN' ORDER BY `id` DESC");
$page_nums = mysqli_num_rows($page_query);    

echo "<div style=\"margin: 1% 2%;\">";
echo "<p>Tickets open: ". $page_nums ."</p>";

if ($page_nums >= 1) {
    echo "<table class=\"ui celled striped table\">";
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "    <td class='tbr tbt'><b>Beschreibung</b></td>";
    echo "    <td class='tbr tbt'><b>Datum</b></td>";
    echo "    <td class='tbr tbt'><b>Besitzer</b></td>";
    echo "    <td class='tbr tbt'><b>Welt</b></td>";
    echo "    <td class='tbr tbt'><b>Admin-Antwort</b></td>";
    echo "    <td class='tbr tbt'><b>User-Antwort</b></td>";
    echo "    <td class='tbr tbt'><b>Status</b></td>";
    echo "    <td class='tbr tbt'><b>Admin</b></td>";
    echo "    <td class='tbr tbt'><b>Antworten</b></td>";
    echo "    <td class='tbr tbt'><b>Schliessen</b></td>";
    echo "</tr>";

    while ($obj = mysqli_fetch_object($page_query)) {
        echo "<tr>";
        echo "<td class='tbr'>" . $obj->description . "</td>";
        echo "<td class='tbr'>" . $obj->date . "</td>";
        echo "<td class='tbr'>" . $obj->owner . "</td>";
        echo "<td class='tbr'>" . $obj->world . "</td>";
        echo "<td class='tbr'>" . $obj->adminreply . "</td>";
        echo "<td class='tbr'>" . $obj->userreply . "</td>";
        echo "<td class='tbr'>" . $obj->status . "</td>";
        echo "<td class='tbr'>" . $obj->admin . "</td>";
    echo "<td><form action='' method='POST'><button class='tbr' type='submit' value='. $obj->date .'>Schliessen</button></form></td>";
        echo "</tr>";
    }
}
echo "</table>";
echo "</div>";


if(isset($_POST['submit'])){

        $con = mysqli_connect($ip, $user, $pw, $db);
        if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
        echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();

    $page_query = mysqli_query($con, "UPDATE `SHT_Tickets` SET `status`='CLOSED' WHERE 'date'=buttonObject.value   ");
        $page_nums = mysqli_num_rows($page_query);
}
}
```

Comment: `buttonObject.value`? What is this? And if there will be two or more tickets with same date - they all will be closed?

Comment: the date contains date as well as time like this "2015-08-29 21:54:28"

Comment: I will look into the syntax errors, still does not fix my problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Works fine on my system. Screen shot [here](http://imgur.com/7gqtqy5) but the below code has the debug info removed. I made the column named date a `datetime` datatype based on your comment under the question.

**Please note** the comment around the UPDATE row area. This should be turned into a **Prepared Statement** due to **injection risk**, and ponder the fact that theoretically there is nothing keeping someone from **closing every ticket** in your system. They could craft a loop that would just do the posts in their own maniacal code. So you need to look at other SESSION info to re-work this.

Turn on error reporting first (first 2 lines).

Also I added a hidden field for the ticket date to update. And that really should be an auto_increment id coming out of the database, not a datetime, for uniqueness. I back-ticked the date column name, and a db close. Moved the UPDATE chunk to the top so it happens then the refresh below it.

### Schema:

```
create table SHT_Tickets
(   id int auto_increment primary key,
    description varchar(100) not null,
    date datetime not null,
    owner varchar(100) not null,
    world varchar(100) not null,
    adminreply varchar(100) not null,
    userreply varchar(100) not null,
    status varchar(100) not null,
    admin varchar(100) not null
);

truncate table SHT_Tickets;
insert SHT_Tickets (description,date,owner,world,adminreply,userreply,status,admin) values
('fenster','2015-09-01 11:00:00','own','w','ar','der Himmel noch blaut','open','admin111'),
('trout','2015-09-02 11:00:00','own','w','ar','zwei','open','admin111'),
('fish','2015-09-03 11:00:00','own','w','ar','drei','closed','admin111'),
('mustard','2015-09-04 11:00:00','own','w','ar','haben Sie etwas?','open','admin111');
```

### this.php:

```
    error_reporting(E_ALL);
    ini_set("display_errors", 1);

    $con = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'xxx', 'yyy', 'dbname');
    if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
        echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
        exit();
    }

    // I am scrared, so I remmed this out
    //if($show_updates == 'true') {
    //    echo file_get_contents('http://zombieland.eu/api/sht/update-1.2.php');    
    //}

    if(isset($_POST['delMe'])){
        // Warning, it was db data to begin with
        // but the poster could fake the data and inject harmful code
        $theDate=$_POST['delMe'];
        $sql="UPDATE `SHT_Tickets` SET `status`='CLOSED' WHERE `date`='$theDate'";

        $page_query = mysqli_query($con, $sql);
        $page_nums = mysqli_num_rows($page_query); // residue left here of no use
    }

    $page_query = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM `SHT_Tickets` WHERE `status`='OPEN' ORDER BY `id` DESC");
    $page_nums = mysqli_num_rows($page_query);    

    echo "<div style=\"margin: 1% 2%;\">";
    echo "<p>Tickets open: ". $page_nums ."</p>";

    if ($page_nums >= 1) {
        echo "<table class=\"ui celled striped table\">";
        echo "<tr>";
        echo "    <td class='tbr tbt'><b>Beschreibung</b></td>";
        echo "    <td class='tbr tbt'><b>Datum</b></td>";
        echo "    <td class='tbr tbt'><b>Besitzer</b></td>";
        echo "    <td class='tbr tbt'><b>Welt</b></td>";
        echo "    <td class='tbr tbt'><b>Admin-Antwort</b></td>";
        echo "    <td class='tbr tbt'><b>User-Antwort</b></td>";
        echo "    <td class='tbr tbt'><b>Status</b></td>";
        echo "    <td class='tbr tbt'><b>Admin</b></td>";
        echo "    <td class='tbr tbt'><b>Antworten</b></td>";
        echo "    <td class='tbr tbt'><b>Schliessen</b></td>";
        echo "</tr>";

        while ($obj = mysqli_fetch_object($page_query)) {
            echo "<tr>";
            echo "<td class='tbr'>" . $obj->description . "</td>";
            echo "<td class='tbr'>" . $obj->date . "</td>";
            echo "<td class='tbr'>" . $obj->owner . "</td>";
            echo "<td class='tbr'>" . $obj->world . "</td>";
            echo "<td class='tbr'>" . $obj->adminreply . "</td>";
            echo "<td class='tbr'>" . $obj->userreply . "</td>";
            echo "<td class='tbr'>" . $obj->status . "</td>";
            echo "<td class='tbr'>" . $obj->admin . "</td>";
            echo '<td><form action="this.php" method="POST"><input type="hidden" name="delMe" value="' . $obj->date . '" /><input type="submit" value="Delete" /></form></td>';
            echo "</tr>";
        }
    }
    echo "</table>";
    echo "</div>";

    mysqli_close($con); // do not forget me
```